# Does not exist in current context. Using a [String]

Tags: c#

I'm confused Please Help!

```
string[] source = Directory.GetFiles(path);

foreach (string sourcefile in source);
    string dest = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);

File.Move(sourcefile, sourcefile);
```

Comment: `foreach (string sourcefile in source);` => is this a typo? You should use both `string dest = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile)` and `File.Move` inside `foreach` scope.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide full exception message, on which line it happens and other valuable information that could help others understanding your problem and easily give you help. As your post currently is, it's too broad.

Comment: Hi. I sympathize with being confused but you should start by outlining what behavior you want to implement, otherwise we will be confused as well.

Comment: Very confused. What was `File.Move(sourcefile, sourcefile);` meant to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] source = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (string sourcefile in source)
{
    string dest = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);
    File.Move(sourcefile, dest );
}
```

you forgot to add braces. Otherwise the foreach just works for the line after.
And you want to move it to `dest` I guess. (Thanks Dmitry)